# Export data of two tables into a single Excel with two worksheets

Tags: excel, oracle, export-to-excel

I am using Oracle database and I need to export data from two tables into a single Excel file having two worksheets using SQL script. I am using the following code to create two worksheets in the 'final_output.xls' file by referring it to 2 independent xls files named 'Source1.xls' and 'Source2.xls'. But the disadvantage of using this method is that the final output file is dependent on its references. If any of the source files get deleted then it won't show up any data.

Is there any way to DIRECTLY populate the data of two tables into two worksheets of single excel file using SQL script? Kindly note that since I have to use it for customer so I can't use any third party tool or any unlicensed code.

```
spool final_output.xls

prompt <HTML xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
prompt  <HEAD>
prompt <meta name="Excel Workbook Frameset">
prompt   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
prompt   <meta content="Excel.Sheet" name="ProgId">
prompt   <meta content="Microsoft Excel 11" name="Generator">
prompt   <LINK href="#ab">
prompt   <LINK href="#xy">
prompt <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
prompt  <x:ExcelWorkbook>
prompt   <x:ExcelWorksheets>
prompt    <x:ExcelWorksheet>
prompt     <x:Name>Report</x:Name>
prompt     <x:WorksheetSource HRef="Source1.xls"/>
prompt    </x:ExcelWorksheet>
prompt    <x:ExcelWorksheet>
prompt     <x:Name>Case_Num</x:Name>
prompt     <x:WorksheetSource HRef="Source2.xls"/>
prompt    </x:ExcelWorksheet>
prompt   </x:ExcelWorksheets>
prompt  </x:ExcelWorkbook>
prompt </xml><![endif]-->
prompt  </HEAD>
prompt  <body>
prompt  </body>
prompt </HTML>
spool off

set markup html on spool on
spool Source1.xls
set heading off

select * from T1;

spool off

spool Source2.xls

select * from T2 ;

spool off
set markup html off spool off

exit ;
```

Comment: There's a [pretty good description of the basic process here](https://community.oracle.com/message/11052667). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `AS_XLSX` package created by Anton Scheffer (http://technology.amis.nl/tag/as_xlsx/). I am using it to generate various reports from the database. The package is free, compatible with Excel 2010, supported multi-sheets and formatting (and lot of more).

sheers,

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as:

```
BEGIN
... 
as_xlsx.clear_workbook;
as_xlsx.new_sheet ('test1');
... 
as_xlsx.new_sheet ('test2');
... 
as_xlsx.save (p_directory => '<your_directory>', p_filename => '<your_file>');
END;
/
```

Look at the API and try ...